# Custom Navigation Item though out the app

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on an app which requires custom Navigation item (title view with two labels and activity indicator) something similar to whats app. I need to implement delegate methods also. App has a base navigation controller on which all view controllers get stacked.

I created one custom UIView and added it to every view controller like this:

```
let myCustomView = MyCustomView()
myCustomView.delegate = self
self.navigationItem.titleView = myCustomView;
```

Is there any way to to prevent doing this and listening to delegate methods in each and every view controller? Should I add this to appDelegate or create custom Navigation Controller. What is the effective way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `AppDelegate` try to create one `BaseViewController`. After that create one function for your custom navigation setting that you want like this.

```
class BaseViewController : UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func customNavigationTitle() {
        let myCustomView = MyCustomView()
        myCustomView.delegate = self
        self.navigationItem.titleView = myCustomView
    }
}
```

Now use this `BaseViewController` as `Parent` of your all `ViewController` so that you can directly access that function

```
 class ViewController : BaseViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       self.customNavigationTitle()
    }
}
```

This will allow you to access all the `delegate` and other method of `BaseViewController`.

Hope this will help you.